# Is there any Spring Scope which equivalent to CDI view-access-scoped

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My project already using CDI @ViewAccessScoped in class. Now am Migrating to Spring boot. It doesn't support @ViewAccessScoped in Spring boot. I need any equivalent scope available in spring boot.

Comment: There isn't an equivalent.

Comment: Is there any way the beans forwarded to the next page and get destroyed automatically. Because in View-scope, bean will get destroyed as soon as navigate to a different page

Comment: The closest is request scope but that is probably destroyed too early. However you are apparently using JSF so why not use the JSF `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Am using spring bean. But JSF @ViewScoped also will get destroyed too early right.

Comment: I would use JSF managed beans (and you can still inject Spring Managed beans into JSF managed beans). `@ViewScoped` should be more or les equivalent to `@ViewAccessScoped`.

Comment: Yes. As of now am using '@ViewScoped' only. Do we can use '@ViewAccessScoped' in Spring.?

Comment: As stated no you cannot.

Comment: okay. Thank you  Deinum. Will check with ViewScope